# Scheduling Rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing a Rails application.

If I have some rake tasks under **lib/tasks**, how to implement the feature to specify my app to run certain rake tasks at 00:00:00 every day (that is, run certain tasks every day at midnight)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest that you use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: Note that you cant use whenever for deploying it to Heroku as it does not support cron. You should use Heroku Scheduler for this

Answer (score 2):

I would setup the rake tasks as specific cron jobs in crontab.  I've used this method to automate archival of older data.  It's handy that you can get an email with the output from rake as well.

Example crontab:

```
MAILTO="me@domain.ext"
0 0 * * * /path/to/archive_script.sh
```

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/.bashrc
cd /path/to/project
export RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake archive_old_items -s
```